# URL Rewriting .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having some problems with the .htaccess file. I'm working on a REST API and I'm rewriting my URL's, if I put .htaccess at the root of my server (localhost) everything works fine, but I actually don't want to put my .htaccess file there but in my project directory.

For example I want to type

```
http://localhost/myproject/player/id/etc..
```

and not just

```
http://localhost/player/id/etc...
```

The problem is that if I use

```
http://localhost/myproject/player/id/etc..
```

The redirection works correctly but in my controller.php file the Path variable I retrieve is /myproject/player/id. Is there a way to remove /myproject/ from the URI in the .htaccess file, or more generally is it possible to remove the directory of the folder containing the .htaccess from the REQUEST_URI variable ?

Comment: are you using any framework?

Comment: no i'm trying to code it by myself to understand how it all works

Comment: How are you accessing the path in your controller?

Comment: $url = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); 
$path = trim($url['path'], "/");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. try this- in your .htaccess write-

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^myproject/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

it will remove myproject from your url.

Comment: so this means that I have to know the directory in advance?

Comment: no, it just means that whenever this directory name comes in the url, it wont get shown!

Comment: ok thanks, i've just tried your code and added RewriteRule ^myproject/(.*)$ /controller.php/$1 [L,NC,R] but this no longer redirects to controller.php, what have I done wrong?

Comment: no. wait! you are misassuming the purpose of .htaccess, this code doesnt redirects any where. it actually, hides your directory name from url, but it doesnt mean that its not present there, its just not getting shown, so your question was  way to remove /myproject/ from the URI in the .htaccess file, this is the way. if there's sumthing else, then tell

Comment: sorry so how can I add controller.php to the URL ?